# Не получается открыть ссылку в новой вкладке 404 Apache server

Tags: apache2

Имеется сервер ubuntu16 c установленным apachе2.
Имеется небольшой сайтик на этом же сервере: несколько страниц.
При открытии ссылок внутри страницы, контент отображается корректно. Если же открыть ссылку извне или в новом окне, то происходит ошибка 404:
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server

Гугл пока не дал результатов по решению этого вопроса.
Подскажите, может нет прав в каких то директориях или нужно что то подправить в конфиге апача?